# How can I post my facebook page visitors post automatically?

Tags: php, facebook, web, automation

My page vistors will post a message on my page(other website is ok), and how can I auto post those post?

I started to thinking using build up a web form and when my user put submit it will auto post to my page.
I have created the web form and build up a facebook app
the id and App Secret is standy by
and what next? or other better solution?

thx

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create a Facebook Application. Then you'll have to integrate that with your website and make sure it has posting permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/

SDK's are here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api